# 400 http code error using PHP & CUrl & gifs.com API

Tags: php, curl

I looked for a sample code for php & curl and i found this link http://www.php-guru.in/2013/upload-files-using-php-curl/

I tried using the code with gifs.com API to try to convert gif to mp4 (for speed reasons) then display it on my site. i tried using a giphy url to upload to gifs.com and so i ended up with the code below.

```
  $url = 'https://api.gifs.com/media/upload';
  $headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data", "Gifs-API-Key:gifkey"); // cURL headers for file uploading
  $postfields = array("file" => "@https://media.giphy.com/media/l378drKbCncSKYbS0/giphy.gif", "title" => 'guineapig');
  $ch = curl_init();
  $options = array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
      CURLOPT_POST => 1,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
  ); // cURL options
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
  $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

  if (!curl_errno($ch)) { 
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo $info['http_code'];
    echo $server_output;
   } else { 
    $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
    echo $errmsg;
  }

  curl_close ($ch);
```

The problem is, it's always showing a 400 http_code and i don't know what the problems is

here is the full error it displays

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server: nginx Date: Thu, 02 Nov 2017 13:44:05 GMT Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 0 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept,Content-Type,Gifs-API-Key Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Access-Control-Max-Age: 43200 Request-Id: 9b78a2d3-0f25-4f13-bb2d-a40b75e6fa8f Via: 1.1 google Alt-Svc: clear
```

I don't understand the error

note: I'm using a localhost xampp server, Is this the cause of it messing up?

Comment: `Bad Request` means, that the Server does not understand the request. Mainly the method is wrong, missing Parameter, wrong Encoding of the Parameter, wrong datatype ...

Comment: To me, it would seem odd for an api endpoint to expect form data. Maybe you need to be sending JSON. In any case, you should look at gifs.com api docs to figure out how to structure your request: https://github.com/gifs/api

Comment: @dan08 i actually did check out their docs [link](http://docs.gifs.com/docs/mediaupload) but maybe I'm looking at this wrong, i'll try modifying the code since i have an idea right now, thanks to both of you

Comment: got it fixed, thanks for giving me an idea, will be posting the answer here

Answer (score 0):

turns out i only needed to use their import API since it's a link to a gif rather than a file upload, so i changed the header with a json instead of a multipart-form

```
  $url = 'https://api.gifs.com/media/import';
  $headers = array("Gifs-API-Key: gifkey", "Content-Type: application/json"); // cURL headers for file uploading
  $postfields = "{\n \"source\": \"https://media.giphy.com/media/l378drKbCncSKYbS0/giphy.gif\",\n \"title\": \"guineapig\",\n \"tags\": [\"crazy\", \"hand drawn\", \"2015\", \"art\"],\n \"attribution\": {\n   \"site\": \"vine\",\n   \"user\": \"someone\"\n }\n}";
  $ch = curl_init();
  $options = array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
      CURLOPT_POST => 1,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
  ); // cURL options
  curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
  $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

  if (!curl_errno($ch)) { 
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo $info['http_code'];
    echo $server_output;
   } else { 
    $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
    echo $errmsg;
  }

  curl_close ($ch);
```